# How to ensure that the behavior of pandas.to_csv() does not change

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda

The following code produces different results in python 2.7.5.final.0 with pandas 0.15.1 and numpy 1.9.1 and in python 2.7.11.final.0 with pandas 0.18.0 and numpy 1.10.4 (the anaconda package).

The former version gives the result  `18292498239.8`; the latter, `18292498239.824`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = 18292498239.824
df = pd.DataFrame({'One': x},index=["bignum"])
df.to_csv('junktest.txt')
fh = open('junktest.txt','rb')
res = fh.read().split('\n')[1].split(',')[1]
print "Result:",res
```

But if we set x to `292498239.824`, we get the same result from both: `292498239.824`. If we go up an order of magnitude (`x = 118292498239.824`), the results are `1.1829249824e+11` and `118292498239.824`.

It looks like the later version of `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()` restricts floats to 12 digits, but I cannot find anything in the pandas documentation to tell when the change occurred -- or why.

This caused some of my unit tests to fail upon upgrading to anaconda; I would like to be able to upgrade without having to substantially revise my tests.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE2:**

you can try to use `np.set_printoptions(precision=20)` function:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=20)
df.to_csv('d:/temp/a.csv', index=False)
```

gives me

d:/temp/a.csv:

```
One
18292498239.824
123456789012345.12
```

NOTE: using pandas 0.18.1

DF:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
            One
0  1.829250e+10
1  1.234568e+14
```

**OLD answer:**

use `float_format='%16.4f'` parameter in the [to_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) call

Docs:

> **float_format** : string, default None
>
> Format string for floating point numbers

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. Not all columns require three decimal places and I don't want trailing zeroes -- unless there's a way to have different float_formats on different columns? I looked, but didn't see any such ....

Comment: it looks like astype(str) also has a 12-character limit. I want the first number to be saved to csv as 18292498239.824. This was the former behavior, after all.

Comment: The problem is not that `to_csv()` changed, but that `csv.writer` changed.

Trying to find when and how this change was made, I found this: http://bugs.python.org/issue13573.

So, in December 2011, `csv.writer` was changed to use `__repr__` instead of `__str__` for floats. Then, sometime before February 2016, it was changed back to use `__str__` instead of `__repr__` and the documentation was changed to reflect this in Feburary 2016. Or, perhaps, the note on bugs.python.org is incorrect ....

Comment: @F.Bartlett, just tested  `np.set_printoptions(precision=20)` before calling `to_csv()` - it does exactly what you need. Tested with pandas `0.18.1`

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.18.0, which may make a difference. But, even after setting `precision=20`,
`df = pd.DataFrame({'One': 18292498239.824},index=["bignum"])`
`df.to_csv('repr_test.csv')`
`!cat repr_test.csv`
produces
`,One
bignum,18292498239.8`
We want to be able to use `to_csv` to save a DataFrame and then recreate a precisely identical copy from the csv file (our testing indicated that this was faster than other methods). The use of `__str__` instead of `__repr__` prevents this; it's not really a matter of precision.